# How do I implement an overloaded copy assignment operator for a reference (proxy) class?

Tags: c++, reference, proxy, operator-overloading, bitarray

As an assignment I have to create a template bit array class and part of it is overloading the index operator.  We are told to use a proxy class and are given a sample code to go off of:

```
class Bits {
...
    class reference {
        Bits& b;
        int pos;
    public:
        reference(Bits& bs, int p) : b(bs) {
            pos = p;
        }
        reference& operator=(bool bit) {
            // Set the bit in position pos to true or false, per bit
            if (bit)
                b.data |= (1u << pos);
            else
                b.data &= ~(1u << pos);
            return *this;
        }
        operator bool () const {
            // Return true or false per the bit in position pos
            return b.data & (1u << pos);
        }
    };
    reference operator[](int pos) {
        return reference(*this, pos);
    }
```

My code reads as follows (altered to fit a bit array):

```
template <class IType = size_t>
class BitArray {
...
    class bitproxy {
        BitArray& b;
        size_t pos;
    public:
        bitproxy(BitArray& ba, size_t p) : b(ba) {
            pos = p;
        }
        bitproxy& operator=(bool bit) {
            b.assign_bit(pos, bit);
            return *this;
        }
        operator bool() const {
            return b.read_bit(pos);
        }
    };

    bitproxy operator[](size_t bitpos) {
        if (bitpos >= arrSize)
            throw logic_error("Provided index is out of range");
        else
            return bitproxy(*this, bitpos);
    }
    bool operator[](size_t pos) const {
        if (pos >= arrSize)
            throw logic_error("Provided index is out of range");
        else
            return read_bit(pos);
    }
```

My code works perfectly and passes all of the tests (the tbitarray.cpp file) when I run it in Visual Studio, but doesn't work when I run it through g++ on my Mac.  Instead it comes up with this error message:

```
tbitarray.cpp:141:17: error: object of type 'BitArray<unsigned long>::bitproxy'
      cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly
      deleted
        b9[0] = b10[0] = b10[1];
                       ^
./BitArray.h:166:13: note: copy assignment operator of 'bitproxy' is implicitly
      deleted because field 'b' is of reference type 'BitArray<unsigned long> &'
                BitArray& b;
                          ^
```

The reference sample code compiles and runs without any issues on both my windows or mac.

I understand why the copy assignment is being implicitly deleted, but what I don't understand is why the sample code works (when it's in the same basic format) and why my code will run on a Windows machine, but not a unix-based machine.

I'm not really sure where to go from here and I've tried just about everything.  Is there some sort of workaround for this?

Comment: `My code works perfectly `  On a side note, you're missing an overload of `operator []` that works on `const` Bit objects.  Your code will not compile if a `const Bits&` is passed to a function, and inside that function you use `Bits::operator[ ]`

Comment: I'm quite doubtful that your sample code will actually compile with a `b10[0] = b10[1];`. Regardless, this will need special semantics. Assigning a proxy to another proxy should read the bit value from the first and assign it to the bit referred to by the second.

Comment: Sorry, just below my first 'operator[]' I have an overload for 'const'.  I'll edit that into my post.

Comment: I'm voting to close because your excerpts do not include the line producing the error or an explanation of why it is there. Presumably it should copy the proxied value instead of the referring members. But without knowing what the operator should do and in what context (which might imply you may want to overload other special methods too), people can't advise how to implement it without speculating. Also, while some weird non-standard-conforming compiler/mode might have compiled and run that code, I doubt it does what you really want. Passing the tests then just means the tests are incomplete.